# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > Error: Failed to crunch file

Tags: android, file

How to solve the error "failed to crunch file"

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: Failed to crunch file FinalProject\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\10.2.1\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png into FinalProject\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png

Comment: Check your Gradle Version

Comment: its 2.2.3 @Mansi Bhatt

Comment: So, please rebuild first and clean your project

Comment: not working , whenever i tries to rebuild same error occure

Comment: ok than Copy the directory one level above and try it may be it's the issue with long path of directory.

Comment: yeah @MansiBhatt, this error occure bcz of LONG PATH, finally solved, you saved my day, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error, when I was using the google plus plugin. I tried to move the project to a smaller path and it worked.

Searching a bit more about it, it seems that Google has a 240 characters size limitation to the path.
Another possible solution, is to add to your platforms/android/build.gradle, inside allprojects, this line:

**`buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"`**

Now your build file will be moved to a smaller path and the problem will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Please change path of your project folder previous path have to long 
Example d:projects/tfs/demos/ionic/projects/project_Name to projects/project_name folder

or

by using "subst" command in command prompt like below

d:projects/tfs/demos/ionic/projects/project_Name folder :subst i: . it will make "i" drive in PC, "i" drive open your project and build it